# Connecting rails to postgresql doesn't work anymore since updating from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, rails

I get this error:

```
“could not translate host name ”db“ to address: Name or service not known”
```

This is my configuration:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: backbone_data_bootstrap_development
  min_messages: WARNING
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  host: db
```

Answer (score 0):

```
host: db
```

`db` as a name of host needs to be resolved to an IP address, either by `/etc/hosts` or by the DNS. Or it needs to be replaced by an IP address.

Possibly in your previous installation there was an entry in `/etc/hosts` that aliased `db` to an address, and your new installation has now a fresh `/etc/hosts`.